# maven dependency:list just first level

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

dependency:list prints entire tree in flat format.

What can I do so it only gives first level only ?

Just to illustrate with dependency:tree

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ abc-service ---
[INFO] xx.xyz.zbc:abc-service:jar:1.82-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.14:test
[INFO] +- org.xmlmatchers:xml-matchers:jar:1.0-RC1:test
[INFO] |  +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.6:test
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |     +- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |     |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.0:test
[INFO] |     \- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:test
```

I just want

```
[INFO] +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.14:test
[INFO] +- org.xmlmatchers:xml-matchers:jar:1.0-RC1:test
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can read in the documentation.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html

`mvn dependency:list -DexcludeTransitive=true`